# Filter in facebook app analytics

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-analytics

Let me give some background first:
I created a facebook app that uses machine learning and face recognition to find people in events (shows, races, conferences, etc). Its main use is to find an user and show the pictures that he's present, with the option of sharing said pictures on facebook. The app is finished, but now I need to have some analytics.

The facebook app analytics is good enough, but there is one case where I need some help. I can see the Click-Through Rate, Impressions and the number of Posts Published. But to the tool, the analytics of all the pictures shared through my app are grouped together.

If I need to see the analytics of just one event, like 'conference A' for example, I can't. Because the number of impressions shown in the tool include all the impressions of 'conference A', 'conference B' and 'conference C'.

Is there anyway that I can have these filtered analytics? Can someone point me the direction where I could solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can see analytics for different events at `https://www.facebook.com/analytics/{your-app-id}/?section=AppEvents`

Comment: Or, rather than build the URL yourself you can just click on the 'Events' link under the 'Activity' section. Breakdowns also allow you to pivot individual events by parameter, which can be very useful.